# How can I check currently logged in user in CAS before deleting any user

Tags: java, scala, cas

I am using SCALA with CAS. I want to check if user is curretly logged in (in CAS) or not before deleting it by using Super user Account. If user is currently loggedin then do not delele him/her.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the gateway feature of the CAS protocol.